# Database db:pg://postgres@/postgres has not been initialized for Sqitch

Tags: postgresql, sqitch

when i try to link sqitch to  postgres local database it return
this issue Database db:pg://postgres@/postgres has not been initialized for Sqitch
with command  sqitch log -u postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no  using version 12.3

Comment: Have you deployed to this database yet? If you haven't deployed anything, it hasn't been initialized, so there's nothing logged.